# Function of a Function Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Is there any function, $f(x)\neq x$, for which $f(f'(x))=f'(f(x))$?

Answer (score 3):

For the real-valued function $f(x)=e^x$, $f'(x)=e^x$.

Comment: Thanks. $f(x)=e^x$ works. What if the condition was $f(x) \neq f'(x) \neq x$?

Comment: There are still many.

Answer (score 1):

Why, many. $f(x)={x^2\over2}$ will do.

If you want to exclude the "trick" answers where $f'(x)=x$ or $f(x)=f'(x)$, go with $f(x)={x^3\over9}$. Other examples are still plenty, I believe.

**Upd.** The other examples seem *less* numerous than I initially believed, but anyway, $f(x)=\dfrac{x^n}{n^{n-1}}$ for any constant $n$ is good.